# Как в bootstrap выровнять текст по левому краю?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap. Есть ли какой то класс который выравняет текст по левому краю, или как-то его красивее сделает? Или это только в ccs править? Хотелось бы просто классом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Comment: а вообще, не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться, ведь по умолчанию текст и так выравнивается по левому краю

Answer (score 2):

Использовать класс `text-left` для тех div,td,tr, какие хотите выровнять по левой стороне.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде нет, используй `float:left`

Comment: или text-align: left;